# ServiceStack.OrmLite: Can custom naming of index be done in code?

Tags: mysql, indexing, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

*(I'm running ServiceStack OrmLite 5.1.1)*

I happen to have a few objects that has a long name, and creating the table as it is setup now creates a table with a long name. When OrmLite tries to create an index on one column, it fails with:

> Could not create table co_BookingRecurring_RecurringBookingAdministrationGroup (type tWorks.Alfa.AlfaCommons.BookingRecurring.RecurringBookingAdministrationGroup): Identifier name 'idx_co_bookingrecurring_recurringbookingadministrationgroup_deleted' is too long

So, I was hoping that the `IndexAttribute` would also contain a constructor so I could change this and it would instead be `idx_deleted`, but there is no such constructor or other way that I found to handle it.

I found the [INamingStrategy](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/INamingStrategy.cs) interface and [some examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.PostgreSQL.Tests/OrmLiteCreateTableWithNamigStrategyTests.cs), but they don't seem to handle index names.

Is there a way to handle this, so that I can use the CreateTable as normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added support for custom index names in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/9beeba7f00b42c03045c07c136664ae1691b1c8a) which will let you provide a custom index name to use instead of the convention-based index name, e.g:

```
public class Table
{
    [Index(Name = "idx_custom_name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This change is available from v5.1.1 that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Greatness. Thanks for always quick and effective support and help =)

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Avoid long user-defined names:  "RecurringBookingAdministrationGroup"

Plan B:  (Or maybe OrmLite is at fault for this):  Don't include the table name ("BookRecurring"?) in the name of anything in the table (except maybe for the 'id').

Plan C:  Get someone to fix OrmLite.  One approach to a fix is to truncate long names and append a fixed length hash of what should have been the overly-long name.

Plan D:  File a bug report with bugs.mysql.com complaining about name limitations.

Plan E:  Look into MySQL 8.0; it may have some increased limits; don't know if they apply here.

(Meanwhile, I'll add this to my long list of why 3rd party software can 'get in the way' more than help.)